# How do I add CDATA as a value to a particular node without using docptr

Tags: c, xml, libxml2, cdata

I wanted to create and xml file like the one below. 
I treated the value of the `child` node as string and added it using the function `xmlNewText(BAD_CAST string)` where string is the value I wanted to place in the child node

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root>
        <child>![CDATA[<data>hello</data>]]</child>
    </Root>
```

But this is converted to

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root>
        <child>![CDATA[&lt;data&gt;hello&lt;/data&gt;]]</child>
    </Root>
```

Can anyone guide me in doing so? I have seen some questions and the answers are based on creating cdatasection using the docptr. I need to create the cdatasection without using the docptr. I just have the rootptr with me. Is it possible to do so? I am using c as the programming language and the library which I am using is libxml

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you are using. Right now I can't even guess.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't construct XML content by inserting it into the DOM as text. This example shows some of the reasons why -- not only is the DOM correctly escaping the content of the text node, but you've got the syntax of  wrong.

Instead, use the node factory to create a CDATASection node containing the text you want to include in the document.

Or -- since there's no good reason to use a CDATA Section here -- create a Text node without trying to manually wrap its contents in , and let the DOM serializer escape it as appropriate. You'll probably get character-by-character escaping, which doesn't look as pretty in the XML file... but it will mean exactly the same thing to any properly-written application processing that XML.

(Admittedly there are some applications which do care about the difference between normal text and CDATA sections. The technical term for those applications is "broken".)